# SQL Select query fIlter between two dates

Tags: sql, oledb

I would like to expand this select query to filter between two dates.

```
    "SELECT * FROM ["&"1_RPA_GBR_AC_022.csv"&"] T "
```

The above select query gets all data from the OLEDB connection File name:1_RPA_GBR_AC_022.csv  and places it into a collection.

I would like to only get data which is between two set dates.

```
 20/03/2023 00:00:00
 27/03/2023 00:00:00


 "SELECT * FROM ["&"1_RPA_GBR_AC_022.csv"&"] T WHERE LastUpdated >= '20/03/2023 00:00:00' AND LastUpdated <= '27/03/2023 00:00:00'"
```

However the syntax error i am receiving is data type mismatch in criteria expression. Any help and guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Connection string used:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & [Extract Folder] & ";Extended Properties = 'text';"
```

Comment: Move the ending `T` to just before `WHERE`. (It's a table alias.)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please add appropriate tag. What this trailing `T` is meant to mean? Have you tried passing dates in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, so `'2023-03-27'`?

Comment: Please note i have updated the question to reflect the two comments

Comment: @SeanBailey not really. `sql` is *not* `SQL Server` from Microsoft. It's the standard query language..

Comment: If it's a data type mismatch why not cast it to proper datatype and try?

Comment: Since this is csv, I would suggest transforming all columns to proper datatypes before querying, also keep in mind data type text is being depreciated in SQL Server so use varchar instead, I would recommend cleansing this column and assigning proper data type for Last Updated, in this case date assuming you are not dealing with datetime.

Comment: I read in a book once that the most compatible date string internationally is 'YYYYMMDD.' Not sure how true that is, but to get to what you're after I'd say LastUpdated >= '20230320.' And, if it's a column that has a timestamp, I'd bump the date up a day and use <instead of <= eg. LastUpdated < '20230328'  Good luck.

Comment: @JohnInk, saving as YYYYMMDD or better ODBC Canonical format (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) or ISO8601 (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss) is correct and doesn't leave space for misinterpretations.  However LastUpdated >= '20230320' wouldn't be right for all drivers. That is something SQL server driver would understand but not JT.OLEDB.

Comment: @JohnInk Due to historical reasons, `yyyyMMdd` is correct specifically for SQL Server for date values _without a time portion_. For other major databases, you usually still want `yyyy-MM-dd`, and if you have a full datetime value (rather than a date only) it gets a little more complicated: you can use either `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss[.fff]` or `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss[.fff]`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Nice. Thanks. I had a feeling there was more to it than that. And it was a MS book I was reading, so it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It is because that you are using JET Oledb driver and it doesn't know that '27/03/2023 00:00:00' means to be a datetime. In other words, your query is showing the importance of using parameters instead of hard coded or user input string values. If you would hard code a datetime literal, then you should do it the right way and write as:

```
#2023/03/27 00:00:00#
```

That is ODBC canonical format, # used as datetime literal "quote".

A better approach is of course to use parameters:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [1_RPA_GBR_AC_022.csv] 
            WHERE LastUpdated >= @start AND LastUpdated <= @end", 
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & [Extract Folder] & ";Extended Properties = 'text';")
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@start", OleDbType.Date).Value = New DateTime(2023, 3, 20)
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@end", OleDbType.Date).Value = New DateTime(2023, 3, 27)
    Dim t As DataTable = New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(t)
    ' Do whatever with t
End Sub
```

Comment: Plus 1, but note that date range queries should generally use an _exclusive_ upper bound (`<` rather than `<=`) for the first moment after the desired range:  `... AND LastUpdated < @end"` and `.Add("@end", OleDbType.Date).Value = New DateTime(2023, 3, 28)`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, you are perfectly right, that is what I say in every opportunity and here I was really lazy to add that. My bad.